# How are string or vector type unsafe?

Tags: c++

I am going through 'The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition'. In

> 1.2.2 Type checking

section, there is a sentence that says

> "Outside of low-level sections of code (hopefully isolated by
> type-safe interfaces), code that interfaces to code obeying different
> language conventions (e.g., an operating system call interface), and
> the implementations of fundamental abstractions (e.g., string and
> vector), there is now little need for type-unsafe code."

I understand that low-level sections of code and operating system call interfaces can be type-unsafe but how are string and vector type-unsafe? or am I understanding it wrongly?

Comment: Note `the implementations of`.  The *interfaces* are type-safe.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense now.

Comment: Note that the statement is permissive, not declarative. The author would accept type-unsafe code in the implementations, but the author does not say there will be type-unsafe code there.

Comment: Is it maybe referring to things like Small String Optimisation? Some implementations of `std::string` essentially behave like a `union` and for short strings hold the value locally and for long strings allocate dynamically. So the mean of each byte of the object varies depending on the length of the string! That's definitely type unsafe.

Comment: As an example of this, up until C++20, there was no way of implementing `std::vector` whilst obeying the rules of C++. The requirements of `vector::data` require you to be able to transmute an array of N elements into an array of M elements in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are string or vector type unsafe?

They aren't type-unsafe interfaces. As your quote states, their *implementations* may use type-unsafe code.

To go into more detail, their implementations need to separate the allocation of storage, and the creation of the elements, which is inherently unsafe to do.

Comment: Why is it inherently unsafe thing to do?

Comment: @ZoomIn Because it opens a door to a host of mistakes that you can do. You can allocate too little memory, you can allocate more than you intended, you can try to create objects in unaligned addresses, you can attempt to create objects in memory where there already is an object, you can forget to call destructors, you can do things in wrong order, etc. When you just create an object normally, all that is taken care of by the type system.